# Screen Flicker on 20.04 with AMD CPU/ Nvidia GPU

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, screen, amd-processor, flicker

I am having a serious screen flicker problem on a laptop with 20.04 and Kernel 5.13.0-27-gneric. I am not sure if the problem came with the recent Kernel upgrade or a little earlier,  but it started Jan 2022. The computer has an AMD 4800H CPU  and an Nvidia RTX 1660 GPU. Also, I have been using NVidia drivers and I would like to use both the (currently flickering) laptop screen and an external monitor. Anny Ideas? Thanks in advance.